# jdbc how to insert mysql SET type?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi
I have a code for table creating:

```
create table clt (id bigint not null, sources set('A1', 'empty', 'A2', 'A3'), text varchar(50));
```

table was created successfully.

now I'm trying to insert data:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = null;
String query = "insert into clt (id, sources, text) values (?, ?, ?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
int it = 0;
stmt.setLong(++it, 25);
stmt.setString(++it, "A1, A2");
stmt.setString(++it, "some text data");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

and gettting an error :(
    exception: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'sources' at row 1

without *sources* everything is ok.
where is my mistake?

thank you.

Comment: Is it the brackets around A1 when you do the setString?

Comment: Might it be because in the schema, the the set item is **A1**, but in your statement you try to add **(A1)** (the parantheses might be the problem)

Comment: The answer from @Ike Walker seems to agree. I've never used SET before myself so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses around `A1`:

```
stmt.setString(++it, "A1");
```

Comment: how to add two elements of SET? A1 and A2

Comment: `stmt.setString(++it, "A1,A2");`