# What Java Class are SQL Sets?

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

When I do an SQL query in java what method do I use to get an SQL set from the result set?
So if I have a table like this:

`CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, myset set("value0","value1","value2"));`

How would I get the value in the `myset` column in Java? Would it just be a string or would it be a list or something else?

Comment: What database dialect is this? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Something else? Please tag appropriate dialect.

Comment: Andreas it is MariaDB.

Comment: And now the question is closed for no apparent reason.
Andreas the question was tagged with SQL from the beginning.

Comment: I know it was tagged SQL from the beginning, but `SET` is not a standard SQL type, so we needed to know which proprietary dialect you're using, so we could adequately answer your question. We certainly shouldn't have to hunt around all the common dialects to figure out what you're taking about.

Comment: As the following related question shows, you treat the `SET` data type as a `String`, using comma-separation when multiple values are present in the set: [jdbc how to insert mysql SET type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5398133/5221149)

Comment: See also the **documentation** of the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) data type, which says: *"A `SET` is a **string** object that can have zero or more values, each of which must be chosen from a list of permitted values specified when the table is created. `SET` column values that consist of multiple set members are specified with **members separated by commas (`,`)**. A consequence of this is that `SET` member values should not themselves contain commas."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is MySQL's SET thing?

It's not part of JDBC, but JDBC has facilities for JDBC drivers to offer support for non-standard types. To set them:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(idx/name, value, targetSqlType);
```

where targetSqlType is optional (if omitted, the type of `value` is used to try to figure it out), and an int. What value should be there? ¯\*(ツ)*/¯  - Let's hope the JDBC driver has an int constant. What should `value` be? ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ - the docs of the mysql JDBC driver should tell you, because the JDBC spec won't.

To fetch them:

```
resultSet.getObject(idx/colname, SomeType.class);
```

Where, again, what `SomeType` is supposed to be is up to the MySQL JDBC driver.

Note that the implementation of MySQL's 'set list' is as a bitset with a single long (64-bit) value. Possibly then, pass longs, or maybe `BitSet`, but most likely the MySQL JDBC driver just doesn't support this at all.

According to the MySQL JDBC driver (which is called Connector/J for some reason) documentation [it is set with, and returns, a String](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

That seems bizarre to me. Give it a try: Make a set, set a few things, and go query it.

EDIT: See also the [MySQL SET type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) docs, which seem to suggest you just.. `.setString(1, "clubs,spades")` and that you get em with `.getString(1)` which would return `"clubs,spades"`. Sooo, no commas in those things and excruciating lack of performance, I guess? Oof.

The good news is, you can interact with MySQL SET types from JDBC. The bad news is, in the most silly way possible.

Comment: Bottom line, the JDBC spec doesn't include this data type, so you are at the mercy of the specific JDBC driver and its version.

Comment: @TheImpaler that's why I looked it up in the MySQL JDBC driver docs :)

Comment: Why does the information that the value of a `SET` column is returned as a `String` seem bizarre, when the documentation of the [`SET` data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) starts out by showing examples of set values in the form of SQL *text literals*, e.g. `''`, `'one'`, `'two'`, and `'one,two'`?

Comment: @Andreas It's SET, not ENUM. ENUM is a __single__ value. As I understand it, in MySQL, a 'SET' is like a java.util.EnumSet. Presumably it's passed along to and from JDBC in the same fashion as in your linked documentation (I'm going to update my answer and include that link too, it seems rather relevant), but we don't make arrays in java with, say: `int[] x = "1,2,3,4";` either. I'd have expected `java.sql.Array` or a custom data type. This is also excruciatingly inefficient. On disk, these things are a __single long__. JDBC ought to prefer performant code. But, MySQL is a crapshoot anyway.

Comment: Did you even read the documentation I linked to? It clearly states that *"a `SET` is a **string** object that can have **zero or more values**, each of which must be chosen from a **list of permitted values**"*. So, yes, I agree that the Java equivalent would be an `EnumSet`. But it then continues: *"For example, a column specified as `SET('one', 'two') NOT NULL` can have any of these values: `''`, `'one'`, `'two'`, or `'one,two'`"* The data type is a **string** type, and the column "value" is returned as a string with the **comma-separated** list of values present in the set.

Comment: If my text and commentary makes you think 'I did not read the documentation', you need to read my text and commentary again, or stop responding with defensive, knee-jerk stuff.